# Can we sample two signals simultaneously using the ADC (analog to digital) of AVR mircocontroller?

Tags: microcontroller, avr

I am making a project of noise cancellation using least mean sqaure algorithms through microcontroller. In that I need two signals to implement LMS algorithm i.e noisy and noise+clean. So my question is how can i sample these signals simultaneously? Is there any way to sample both signals at the same time?

Comment: What is the model of your AVR μc?

Comment: Realistically, an AVR is not a good choice for an audio DSP application.  Consider using either a DSP chip, or at least a higher performance general purpose micro (ARM, etc).

Answer (score 2):

Tell us more about your signals. If they're slow enough, you may be able to get away with using on the onboard ADC. You didn't say which AVR model you're using, but most AVRs I've used had a maximum sampling frequency of around 4kHz. If you need to sample two signals with it, the ADC is multiplexed, so cut that in half. Unless your signals are significantly slower than that (and without trying it, I would guess a factor of 10 would be pushing it), I would go with a two-channel external ADC. The goal is to sample fast enough that relative to the slower signal, the samples were taken at approximately the same time. The multiplexer in the onboard and some external ADCs will take some finite time to switch. This needs to be considered. The uC clock also needs to be running fast enough that it can complete the necessary math before the next samples.

Answer (score 1):

The AVR XMEGA-A series can sample several signals in parallel. Read AVR1300 for more information. From my understanding you can sample 2 values with only 1 ADC clock cycle delay, which isn't simultaneously but close.
THis is as far as i know the best you can get from the AVR series.

From AVR1300:
" [...] Each signal propagates through the pipeline, where one bit is converted at each stage. In this way the ADC in the XMEGA A is capable of sampling one signal every ADC clock cycle, even if each signal must propagate through all stages in the pipeline before the result is ready in the result register. The propagation time for one single signal conversion through the pipeline is 7 ADC clock cycles for 12-bit conversions and 5 cycles for 8-bit conversions. [...] At full utilization the XMEGA A ADC delivers one result every ADC clock cycle [...]"

Comment: It should be noted that the ATXmega and ATmega are different microcontroller series.

Answer (score -1):

If you really need the samples to be taken at the very same time (you don't) a number of microchip dspic have 2 internal independant ADs. Use their parametric search tool to find them. Or, use an external ADC.

Comment: If you think the OP doesn't really need simutaneous sampling, you should explain why.

Comment: Actually some dsPICs have two internal A/Ds whether he really needs the samples to be taken at the same time or not.

Comment: @Dave Tweed - the lack of a need for truly simultaneous sampling should be obvious given that this is an audio application.  What the actual skew tolerance between channels is depends on a number of unstated factors, but it is clearly not zero.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: You're a bit late to this conversation, but I don't agree that all audio applications are not sensitive to skew. I once worked on an audio project where inter-channel timing had to be controlled to within 1 us. Now, while this does not necessarily require simultaneous sampling, given what the OP is trying to do, I can believe that his algorithm is predicated on simultaneous sampling. This is why I asked this answerer to explain his assertion.

Comment: Please explain what the alleged consequence of 2uS skew would have been in the application you mention.

Comment: Well, this is going way off-topic, but OK. This was an FM broadcast simulcast system, in which we were using T1 lines to distribute stereo audio to multiple transmitter sites. Same-frequency simulcast only works well at the receiver (in the overlap regions) if the modulation on each of the transmitters is time-aligned to within 1 us.

Comment: @DaveTweed - if you need that degree of time alignment, then you have a bandwidth far beyond "audio" and are not in fact an audio application, even if the product after demodulation of this non-audio signal ultimately is a couple of audio signals.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: I'm sorry, but in this case, you really have no idea what you're talking about. Bandwidth and time alignment are completely unrelated. Do you understand the mechanism by which +/- 1us of random timing jitter will reduce the SNR of a 1-kHz sinewave to about 47dB? Demodulating simulcast FM is analogous to that, and yes, the requirements for commercial radio really are that tight.

Comment: @DaveTweed - your signal, before it is demodulated, is NOT audio.  Nor does this discussion concern jitter - rather it concerns a constant skew between channels, as would be achieved by sampling them in turn one slightly after the other with the same converter, rather than at the same instant.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: My signal most certainly was two channels (stereo) of baseband audio. The fact that it subsequently went into an FM stereo modulator is irrelevant. And I AM talking about a constant offset -- a worst-case constant offset of 2 us between two transmitters will cause the jitter I described *at the receiver*.

Comment: Look, this whole conversation started because you asserted that no "audio" application ever needs precise time alignment. I'm providing a counterexample. I also believe that the OP's original application of adaptive noise cancellation may have similar requirements, and was challenging this answerer's offhand and unqualified assertion that it did not. (Note that he never responded...)

Comment: @DaveTweed - you do not seem to understand the difference between constant offset and random jitter, or between audio and encoded data.  Care to figure out what an offset of 1 uS is in terms of audio propagation distance (about a third of a millimeter), and reconsider?

Comment: I think I should point out that the OP just said "noise canceling", not "audio noise canceling". It could be ultrasonic, or even something more exotic.